# Is this class a builder?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Thanks to this class:

https://github.com/WebPajooh/TeleBot/blob/master/src/InlineKeyboard.php

I can build keyboards step by step:

```php
$keyboard = new InlineKeyboard()
    ->addCallbackButton('Start', 'start_callback')
    ->addCallbackButton('Help', 'help_callback')
    ->addUrlButton('FAQ', 'https://example.com/faq')
    ->get();
```

The output of `get()` method is an object encoded by `json_encode()`.

My question is:

1. Can we consider this class a builder?
2. If answer is no, why?
3. Its output is not an object, but a string; does it mean that it is not implementing builder pattern?

Comment: Does it matter? This is primarily opinion based since there is no official definition of any pattern. I would consider it a builder since it builds something, others might disagree.

Comment: Il definitely looks like a builder.

Comment: @luk2302, it does matter. One purpose of design patterns (perhaps the primary purpose) is to provide a common vocabulary. If I say "builder" and you say "builder" but we mean two completely different things, then we can't communicate. And design patterns are a communication tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As wiki says:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

> The builder pattern is a design pattern designed to provide a flexible
> solution to various object creation problems in object-oriented
> programming

As your code creates `InlineKeyboard` with some buttons such as `urlButton` and etc, then it looks like it is Builder pattern.

In addition, [Fluent interface pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) can be seen here as there are chainable methods such as:

```
->addCallbackButton('Start', 'start_callback')
->addCallbackButton('Help', 'help_callback')
->addUrlButton('FAQ', 'https://example.com/faq')
->get()
```